# How can I get the id of a record in a d3 scatter plot?

Tags: d3.js

I have already attached my data and assigned the ids as follow:

```
svg.selectAll("circle").data(csv).enter().append("circle")
                    .attr("id", function(d){return "row"+d["ROW ID"];});
```

"ROW ID" is the name of the column that contains the ids of my data.
Now I want to add an on-click event to the circles and save the ID of the currently point in a new variable to use it to call other function.
Can anyone tell me how to get the "ROW ID" of the currently selected point?

thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you want something like this or have I misunderstood your question?

```
svg = d3.select("svg");

csv = [
  {"row ID": "id1",
   "x": 20,
   "y": 30},
  {"row ID": "id2",
   "x": 30,
   "y": 50}

]

svg.selectAll("circle").data(csv).enter().append("circle")
  .attr("id", function(d){return "row"+d["ROW ID"];})
  .attr("cx", function(d){return d.x})
  .attr("cy",function(d){return d.y})
  .attr("r",10)
  .style("fill", "black");

circles = d3.selectAll("circle");

circles.on("click",function(d) {
  alert(d["row ID"]);
})
```

Interactive version here:  http://tributary.io/inlet/5455132