# How can i get row id when clicking on circle in scatter plot in d3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have plotted one scatter plot in d3.js.
Now i want to get row id when clicking on any circle in scatter plot.

```
my graphdatanew = [
{'x':1,'y':2,'row_id':0},
{'x':12,'y':3,'row_id':1},
{'x':3,'y':20,'row_id':2}]
```

my d3 scatterplot code-

```
const chart = d3.select('.chart')
      .attr('width', width + margins.left + margins.right)
      .attr('height', height + margins.top + margins.bottom)
      .append('g')
      .attr('transform','translate(' + margins.left + ',' + margins.top + ')');
      var yScale = d3.scaleLinear()
      .rangeRound([0,height])
      .domain([yscale2,yscale1]);
      var xScale = d3.scaleLinear()
      .rangeRound([0,width])
      .domain([xscale1,xscale2]);


    const dots = chart.selectAll('dot')
      .data(graphdatanew , null, 2)
      .enter().append('circle')
      .attr('r', 5)
      .attr('id', d => { return d["row_id"]}) =======>here i am returning id
      .attr('cx', d => {return xScale(d.x); })
      .attr('cy', d => {return yScale(d.y)})
      .on("click", function(d){
        console.log("row id is-", d["row_id"])
        clickDot(d)
      })

      .style('fill', (d) => {
         return 'black'
       });
```

I found some solution on stackoverflow

[How can I get the id of a record in a d3 scatter plot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16200935/how-can-i-get-the-id-of-a-record-in-a-d3-scatter-plot)

[How to make scatterplot highlight data on-click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37732166/how-to-make-scatterplot-highlight-data-on-click)

but it is not working for me.

I am not getting, where i am doing wrong.

Please help

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem: https://jsfiddle.net/oprqdcfj/

Comment: @GerardoFurtado yes it is working fine here but in mine case i am getting undefined

Comment: I am using d3v4